# How do you actually use EMMS?

Tags: emms

Could someone explain in a very general sense how EMMS is intended to be used?  I am a refugee from the world of GUI music players and perhaps my mind has been warped by that.  But I haven't been able to understand from the official documentation the basic idea of what functions to call at what time.

I am generally pretty Emacs-literate, and have installed EMMS.  I've managed to get tracks playing by a kind of process of trial and error.  I've even managed to fumble my way to creating a playlist and saving it.  But I haven't figured out how to re-load it later and use it again.

It seems that the playlist is the central abstraction in EMMS, and I gather that your whole library is basically a playlist (?) but I'm not sure where to go from there, or how to use it on a "day-to-day" basis.

If I have, for example, a playlist that I've saved, it seems like maybe the idea is that I have to first do `emms-playlist-new` to create an empty buffer to hold the saved playlist, then I have to be in that buffer and do `emms-insert-m3u-playlist` (or similar, depending on the type of the playlist) and then I can use the playlist -- though the lines are just the file names, not track name, artist name, etc.  Is this really the way EMMS is intended to be used, or am I missing something that makes it simpler?

Thanks for any help....

Comment: This post is currently very broad, which doesn't fit well with the SE format.  Could you narrow it down to a discrete question, please?

Comment: Possibly there is no intended usage, anybody does as he likes.  Currently I use emms via (emms-play-url "http://my_favorite_radio.chan/play.m3u").  And then the M-x emms buffer for stopping and resuming.

Comment: I dont' know ! I use mpg123.el (in MELPA), but it isn't such feature rich. Here you have some basic doc about emms too: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Media_player#Mpg123

Comment: I believe that the close votes can be avoided if you changed the title of the question to ask about loading of a saved play-list (this would be a question easier to answer in the format of SE, and it seems like this is, technically, what you are after).

Comment: Just back in 2021 to reassert - it's a nightmare. I cant figure out playlists at all. And that's just trying to create one from selections in another. It seems you must create a playlist wit all your thousands of tracks and edit that. aargh.

Answer (score 2):

As for track name etc, you'll want to require `emms-info` and one or more of the `emms-info-*` modules (`emms-info-mp3info`, `emms-info-ogginfo` etc), and also make sure that the corresponding command line tools are installed (see if you can run `mp3info` in the terminal). Then add `emms-info-initialize-track` to `emms-track-initialize-functions`. (The setup function `emms-standard` attempts to do all of this for you.)

Answer (score 0):

The key command here is `emms-play-playlist` which is one of a whole family of such commands: see [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72852/how-to-load-previously-saved-emms-playlists/72955) for more.