# How to load previously saved EMMS playlists?

Tags: emms

I've been following the instructions on how to setup EMMS from both this [MakeTechEasier article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-emacs-to-play-music-with-emms/) and the respective [GNU Wiki page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Quickstart-Guide), and I have successfully set up EMMS so that it can create playlists, play songs, and save playlists inside Emacs.

Everything has been pretty much working as I expected to, except that I have been unable to load playlists that I have previously saved. I've tried saving to each of the three available playlist formats (native, pls, m3u) using `emms-playlist-save`, but every time I restart Emacs and try to load a playlist that I have previously saved in any of those formats using `emms-playlist-mode-load-playlist` or `emms-playlist-mode-open-buffer`, the minibuffer returns "Not an EMMS playlist buffer" and fails to play any of the saved playlists.

[I did see this post from 7 years ago](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/how-do-you-actually-use-emms), and it seems that this person was having the exact same problem and experience that I'm having, but nobody answered his question. He had also figured out how to install EMMS, play tracks, and create and save playlists, but had been unable to load previously saved playlists by using `emms-playlist-mode-load-playlist`.

I suppose I could use EMMS by doing that person's solution of running `emms-playlist-new` and using `emms-insert-m3u-playlist` to put a previously saved playlist into an EMMS buffer that will play the tracks. While that does manage to play the tracks, it would make more sense to me that there's probably an easier way to load and manage playlists in EMMS.

Comment: Does `emms-play-playlist` not work for you?

Comment: You've solved my question! That's the command I've been looking for, but I guess I didn't find it because I was expecting it to be worded as ```emms-playlist-play``` since that would've been consistent with other similarly named functions that I had seen. In hindsight however, that wording makes sense since your answer lead me to find other similar commands like ```emms-play-directory``` and ```emms-play-dired``` which can play songs without needing to create a playlist file at all. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `emms-play-playlist`.  In fact, there is a family of `emms-play-*` functions:

- emms-play-playlist-directory
- emms-play-playlist-directory-tree
- emms-play-directory-tree
- emms-play-dired
- emms-play-url
- emms-play-m3u-playlist
- emms-play-native-playlist
- emms-play-playlist-file
- emms-play-pls-playlist
- emms-play-streamlist
- emms-play-file
- emms-play-find
- emms-play-playlist
- emms-play-directory

Comment: Perfect, this is what I've been looking for. I would recommend posting your answer here too, since this person was asking the exact same question that I was several years ago: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/how-do-you-actually-use-emms

Comment: Done!  Now if you would like to accept my answer, that would be very nice!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that was what the gray/green checkmark is supposed to do (still new to StackExchange). I've accepted your answer.